# Why is my function running with phone plugged in but does not run normally?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In this SwiftUI project, I am running a function when the app is launched. The function checks if the users data is up to date. If it isn't, it inserts the new data into the database.

The function was working as expected but has stopped working. I think it could be due to the changes I had to make to the Info.plist regarding BackgroundTasks before distributing the app to App Store Connect to use on TestFlight. This might be the cause but I dont know.

How can I fix this error? Here is my project:

```
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks
import GoogleMobileAds
import Combine
import UserNotifications
import Foundation

@main
struct TestingApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate2.self) var appDelegate2

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in

                })
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks
import HealthKit

class AppDelegate2: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func getDataOnLaunch(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        
        print("APP LAUNCHED - FUNCTION EXECUTED - insert to database if needed")
        
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on why the function worked when I plugged my phone in and ran the code but not when my phone was not plugged in?

Comment: You have references to background tasks but haven't shown any code related to background tasks. When you run your app from Xcode while connected to your Mac, you app gets unlimited background execution time. This is not the case when running a released app. This could be your issue, but you haven't shown enough code.

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah, this code does not reference background tasks however It seemed as though when I changed BackgroundTask stuff in the Info.plist it seemed to stop working. This function I spoke about should execute the function at launch, is this related to Background and will this be possible in a released app? The function checks fetches data via an API and uploads that data into the database.

Comment: Do not forget that when an application start it has a limited time for initialisation. Check in console to see the exception. If you need to execute long time unit better add a task to do it so application can start faster.